# Inno Setup: rich tooltips in component list

Tags: inno-setup

How can I create a custom tooltips in component list of my installer? Basically, I need to show some rich text (image, description) when user moves mouse pointer over components.

Puprose of this is to give user some detailed info on each component he's about to install.

Comment: This will be complicated. First you need to let the InnoSetup populate the `Application` instance, where's the `OnHint` event, which you need to implement or, maybe you might try to catch the `CM_HINTSHOW` message in the window proc. The second, more complicated part is to create a library, that will show the hints as you want. Both steps might be done at once if you make your own InnoSetup build though.

Comment: You can't do this natively.
There is a [sample script](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno.php) that adds extra information to `[Types]`. This can probably be adapted to do the same for `[Components]`

Comment: @TLama - the most problematic point: "if you make your own InnoSetup build"

Comment: @RobeN, but the simplest if you have Delphi ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Inno Setup can't do this natively.